# Jquery Timepicker Script Tags

Tags: jquery

I cannot get the jquery timepicker to work for my web app, though I somehow managed to get the datepicker to work. I think the issue lies with the information I include in my header. Am I not providing the right stuff? What do script tags even mean? I have copies of jquery.timepicker.css/js in the same directory as my html file, but do I need to reference those in the head of the html file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Columbia Ride Share</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="post-ride.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  $("timepicker").timepicker({
      startTime: "00.00"
      timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
      interval: 60,
      endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 30, 0), 
      separator: ':',
      step: 15});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <header> 
       // .....
  </header>
  <div class = "form">
      <form action="action_page.php">
         <label for="airport">Airport</label>
         <select id="airport" name="airport">
             <option value="jfk">JFK</option>
             <option value="laguardia">Laguardia</option>
             <option value="newark">Newark Liberty</option>
         </select>

         <label for="day">Day</label>
         <input type="text" id="datepicker">

         <label for="time">Time</label>
         <p>Between</p> <input type="text" class="timepicker"> 
         <p>And</p><input type="text" id="timepicker">

   </div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try by removing the cdn link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
```

and just use jquery.timepicker.css/js files you have in the same directory as the html file. Yes you would use them by referencing those files in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, JavaScript code must be inserted between `<script> and </script>` tags.You can place any number of scripts in an HTML document. Scripts can be placed in the , or in the  section of an HTML page, or in both. The scripts in head will execute first during page load and scripts inside body will execute as they reach. In your case, what you are doing wrong is declaring the library inside body tag and using it in head tag. So during page initialization it has no idea about timepicker. You have to write your script tag to include timepicker.js before the timepicker initialization code. To do that, either you need to move the CDN import of timepicker.js inside head before initialization code or you can move initialization code from head to body after timepicker CDN import.